# Path in binary tree - Prolog

Tags: prolog, binary-tree

I have a problem with this homework. I have to write code in prolog which will show me deepest way to the leaf of the tree.

Tree is represented as:

```
tree([ [ [],r,[[],u,[[],t,[]]]  ], a ,  [ [], c, [] ]])
```

Where is [ ] like nil and a is a root.

It should have show me something like this: `PATH = [a, r, u, t]`

I will be very thankful.

Solution:

```
deepest(T,D) :- aggregate(max(L,P),(path(T,P),length(P,L)),max(_,D)).

path([],[]).
path([L,K,R],[K|P]) :- path(L,P) ; path(R,P).
```

Test:

```
?- tree(T),deepest(T,P).
T = [[[], r, [[], u, [[], t|...]]], a, [[], c, []]],
P = [a, r, u, t].
```

Comment: The tree looks like this: [Tree](http://i.imgur.com/wcabf7V.png) @repeat

Comment: `%Tree
tree([ [ [],r,[[],u,[[],t,[]]]  ], a ,  [ [], c, [] ]]).
%Homework 1
%Interface: most_dep_path(TREE,PATH):-
%Example to testing:
%tree(X),most_dep_path(X,PATH),print(X).
%Expected result:
%X = [[[], r, [[], u, [[], t|...]]], a, [[], c, []]],
%PATH = [a, r, u, t].` I apologize for the code. It looks like a mess. :/ @repeat

Comment: @Bampelito you should edit your question and add your code there, then it won't be such a mess. The comment area is not a good place to add code.

Comment: Thanks for tip I am just new here :) @lurker

Answer (score 1):

I know, we should not do HWs... but this solution - as is - will probably not be adeguate for your class. Anyway, hope it will help you how to tackle such kind of problems in Prolog.

```
deepest(T,D) :- aggregate(max(L,P),(path(T,P),length(P,L)),max(_,D)).

path([],[]).
path([L,K,R],[K|P]) :- path(L,P) ; path(R,P).
```

test:

```
?- tree(T),deepest(T,P).
T = [[[], r, [[], u, [[], t|...]]], a, [[], c, []]],
P = [a, r, u, t].
```

note: after you grasp the basic of this language, usually no debug is required. The solution is declarative enough...

Comment: Nice and simple solution. I thought it will be little harder to write it. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Since this is a homework, I won't give you the solution straight away.

First, let's have a look at your tree structure. When you look at the tree, you can see one of two options: either it would be a nil represented as `[]`, or it will be a node with a value and two subtrees `[LeftSubTree, Value, RightSubTree]`. Your predicate should therefore have two clauses for the two cases.

In these two cases, what is the deepest path? Well, for nil the answer is easy: there are no nodes, therefore the longest path is actually an empty list.

For a tree node that is not a nil, what will the longest path look like? It will start with with value in current node and continue to either left or right subtree, depending on which is deeper. Thus to get a deepest path from a node, compute the deepest path recursively in the left and right subtree, take the longer of them and plop value from current node in the front.

To implement it this way, you will find it very convenient to have a helper predicate `longer(List1, List2, LongerList)` that will put the longer of `List1` and `List2` into `LongerList`.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a pure variant that doesn't require all-solution meta-predicates like `aggregate/3`.

First, here's your sample tree again:

```
sampleTree([[[],r,[[],u,[[],t,[]]]],a,[[],c,[]]]).
```

Next, `is_tree/1` defines what trees look like:

```
is_tree([]).
is_tree([Left,_,Right]) :-
   is_tree(Left),
   is_tree(Right).
```

Finally, we define `tree_leftmostLongestPath/2` which we use for [pre-order tree traversal](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tree_traversal#Pre-order).

Compared to `is_tree/1`, `tree_leftmostLongestPath_/4` has 3 additional arguments:

- `RPath` which is the path so far in *reversed* order
- `Best0` is a pair `Len-Path` and holds the longest path found *so far*
- `Best` also is a pair `Len-Path` and holds the longest path of the entire tree/subtree

Here's the code:

```
:- use_module(library(clpfd)).

tree_leftmostLongestPath(Tree, Path) :-
   tree_leftmostLongestPath_(Tree, [], 0-[], _-Path).

% "internal" auxiliary predicate
tree_leftmostLongestPath_([], RPath, Best0, Best) :-
   Best0 = L0-_,
   length(RPath, Len),
   (  Len #=< L0,                       Best = Best0
   ;  Len #>  L0, reverse(RPath, Path), Best = Len-Path
   ).
tree_leftmostLongestPath_([Left,Name,Right], RPath, Best0, Best) :-
   RPath1 = [Name|RPath],
   tree_leftmostLongestPath_(Left , RPath1, Best0, Best1),
   tree_leftmostLongestPath_(Right, RPath1, Best1, Best).
```

Some queries and answers:

```
?- sampleTree(Tree), tree_leftmostLongestPath(Tree, Path).
Path = [a,r,u,t], Tree = [[[],r,[[],u,[[],t,[]]]],a,[[],c,[]]]).

?- is_tree(Tree), tree_leftmostLongestPath(Tree, Path).
   Path = []     , Tree = []
;  Path = [A]    , Tree = [[],A,[]]
;  Path = [A,B]  , Tree = [[],A,[[],B,[]]]
;  Path = [A,B,C], Tree = [[],A,[[],B,[[],C,[]]]]
…
```

Comment: I wonder what you mean by "pure" in your first sentence. Could you please explain?

Comment: Now I see what you mean, thanks. But note that  "pure" in this context will most probably taken as meaning "pure Prolog" and that is not what you mean and may lead to confusion. Let me add that your meaning of "pure" is a bit too general: if one can hide cuts and other such side-effects in predicates that "behave as if it were pure" then all predicates except the  top-level one may be impure in your sense.

Comment: I see what you mean, but I fail to see the point of having code that looks externally pure as in (2) unless it is written for presenting it to people, namely when their knowledge of Prolog is scarce. Or maybe when it is written just in answer to a challenge...

Comment: NTS switch to proper tree representation (instead of abusing lists).